# Linear functional not in SOT dual

Tags: functional-analysis

Let H be a Hilbert space and e_{n} be an orthonormal basis of H. Let B(H) be the set of all bonded linear operators on H. Define $\phi(A)=\underset{n}\sum(\frac{1}{2})^{n}\langle A e_{n},e_{n}\rangle$ for $A\in B(H)$. Can anyone help me showing that $\phi$ is not continuous with respect to strong operator topology on B(H)?

Answer (score 0):

This statement is false. In other words, $\phi $ is necessarily continuous. Let $A_k \to A$ in SOT. Since $\{A_k x\}$ is bounded for each $x \in H$, Uniform Boundedness Principle shows that $\sup \{||A_k||\}<\infty $.  This implies that $\sum_n \frac 1 {2^{n}} \langle A_k e_n,e_n \rangle \to \sum_n \frac 1 {2^{n}}\langle A_k e_n,e_n \rangle$ since the $n-th$ term conceges for each $n$ and, given $\epsilon >0$ we can find $N$ such that $\sum_{n>N} |\frac 1 {2^{n}} \langle A_k e_n,e_n \rangle | <\epsilon$, $\sum_{n>N} |\frac 1 {2^{n}} \langle A e_n,e_n \rangle | <\epsilon$

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question. Here $\phi$ is clearly faithful. But we know that no wot continuous linear functional on B(H) is faithful when H is infinite dimensional. In particular $\phi$ is not WOT continuous. Since WOT dual and SOT dual are same $\phi$ should not be SOT continuous as well. This is not true by your argument. Pls help me finding out the error.